# MonoGame window is huge although it should be small

Tags: monogame

I'm using Monogame to create a simple game.

In my Game1 class initializer I set this:

```
Graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
Graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1024;
Graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

My screen resolution is 2560x1600, so the window should be relatively small on startup. However, it's filling the entire screen and more. Why is that? I'm new to this so I have no idea what other information you might need to help me.

Thanks

EDIT: Okay, it had something to do with me messing with the Configuration Manager. There, I tried adding x64 support (no idea, if that's necessary). I'm not sure what I did there, though. I thought I deleted everything I added. However, after reverting the project to the last commit, the problem is gone. What happened there? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On MS Windows**

Are you on a high DPI setting and [does your application manifest declare DPI-awareness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Many parts of WinAPI use Device-Independent Pixels, and whether 1280 means pixels or DIPs (on a display with 2x DPI scaling, that's 2560 physical pixels) depends on how your application declares its DPI awareness.

I've encountered [some interesting behavior](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/5959) in Monogame with regards to DPI handling, so for best results check both your dpiAware and dpiAwareness settings in the manifest.

---

**Non-Windows**

I don't have experience with Monogame on other platforms, so hopefully someone else can answer to that. I believe OSX native APIs also use DIPs, so should show the same effect.

Comment: I can check it, thanks. But I don't think, it's related to that (besides, I have an extremely low DPI) .The thing is, it was working perfectly fine until I messed around with the configuration manager. So it's probably something with that

Comment: "By DPI setting" i mean the "UI scaling setting in windows", not the physical dots per inch on your monitor. For example, my current laptop display is 3200x1800 pixels, at 200% dpi scaling, which means its dimensions is 1600x900 DIPs. (https://imgur.com/a/OUc4Mdk)

Comment: Oh okay. Yeah, it is on 200%. But it still doesn't explain what happened, I think. It worked before, like I said (even with 200% scaling)

Comment: The default app.config Visual Studio generates for you includes a `dpiAware=true` setting. If you're using ConfigurationManager in a way that bypasses the default app configuration, `dpiAware` will be default to false if your own configuration doesn't set it.

Comment: That totally makes sense! Thank you for explaining this. Now it seems likely that this caused it. I will try to confirm it tomorrow and then I will accept this answer. Thanks!